# linq .Value Nullable Object must have a value. How to skip?

Tags: c#, linq

I have some linq code that is sometimes `null`:

```
        cbo3.ItemsSource = empty.Union(from a in
                                           (from b in CompleteData
                                            select b.TourOpID).Distinct()
                                       select new ComboBoxItemString() { ValueString = a.Value.ToString() });
```

But `TourOpID` is sometimes `null` throwing an error on `a.Value.ToString()` . How do I solve this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem occurs because you access the [`Value` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydkbatt6.aspx) of a `Nullable` type which is `null` (or, more precisely, whose `HasValue` property is `false`). How to fix this depends on what you want to do:

1. If you want to filter out items where `TourOpID` is null, just add a `where` clause:

   ```
   ...
   (from b in CompleteData
    where b.TourOpID != null         // filter
    select b.TourOpID).Distinct()
   ...
   ```
2. If you want to use a replacement value, e.g. `0`, if `TourOpID` is null, use the [null coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) `??`, which converts your `int?` into an `int`:

   ```
   ...
   (from b in CompleteData
    select b.TourOpID ?? 0).Distinct()
   ...
   ```

   or, alternatively,

   ```
   ...
   select new ComboBoxItemString() { ValueString = a.GetValueOrDefault().ToString() });
   ```
3. If you just want to show a different ComboBox entry if `TourOpID` is null, use the ternary operator `?:`:

   ```
   ...
   select new ComboBoxItemString() { 
       ValueString = (a == null ? "no tour operator" : a.Value.ToString())
   });
   ```

   If you want to show the empty string if `a` is null, the solution is even simpler:

   ```
   ...
   select new ComboBoxItemString() { ValueString = a.ToString() });
   ```

   since [Nullable.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hd15ket.aspx) returns an empty string if it does not have a value.

Answer (score 1):

use `where`

```
from b in CompleteData where b.TourOpID != null select b.TourOpID
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't You just use `ValueString = a.ToString()` instead of `ValueString = a.Value.ToString()`. If `a` has a value it will return this value to string, if not - `a.ToString()` will return empty string.

```
IEnumerable<decimal?> arr = new List<decimal?>
                                            {
                                                1m, 4m, null, 10m, 6m
                                            };

foreach (var @decimal in arr)
{
       Console.WriteLine(@decimal.ToString());
}
```

The output is:

```
1
4

10
6
```

Answer (score -1):

```
summaryViewModel.MisroutedCount = documentQueryList.Where(p => (p.IsMisrouted == null ? false : p.IsMisrouted == true) && (p.ModifiedDateTime == null ? false : p.ModifiedDateTime.Value.Date == DateTime.Now.Date)).ToList().Count;
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Just one line of unrelated code can never answer a question. When answering questions, use the code in the question and explain which part solves the problem.