# nullable object must have a value error in linq to sql in vb.net code

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, linq

when I debug the code below error nullable object must have a value returned on line `objLstRole = objLstRole.Where(Function(x) x.HQA = UserInfo.HQA).ToList()`

```
Dim objLstRole As New List(Of Common.Role)()
                    objLstRole = r.selectAll().ToList()
                    Dim UI As Common.Objects.User = Session("userinfo")
                    If Not UI.TrainingCenter Then
                        objLstRole = r.selectAll().ToList()
                        TxtPassword.TextMode = TextBoxMode.SingleLine
                    Else
                        objLstRole = objLstRole.Where(Function(x) x.TrainingCenter = True).ToList()
                        TxtPassword.TextMode = TextBoxMode.Password
                    End If

                    If UserInfo.User_Id <> "Admin" Then
                        If UserInfo.HQA Then
                            objLstRole = objLstRole.Where(Function(x) x.HQA = UserInfo.HQA).ToList()
                        ElseIf UserInfo.Field Then
                            objLstRole = objLstRole.Where(Function(x) x.Field = UserInfo.Field).ToList()
                        End If
                    End If
```

Please any advise how can I solve this problem...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [linq .Value Nullable Object must have a value. How to skip?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633806/linq-value-nullable-object-must-have-a-value-how-to-skip)

Answer (score 0):

finally I found reason.. this happens cause **HQA** column in roles table null so I should check it before say where in list collection:

```
objLstRole = objLstRole.Where(Function(x) x.HQA IsNot Nothing And x.HQA = UserInfo.HQA).ToList()
```